# React.js: How to set default value in Select option?

Tags: reactjs

I am trying to implement `select-option` in React using `custom hooks` and encountered an issue while trying to set a default value in `select option`. 
 From the fetched data in `UI`, that comes from web API, I was able to show `selected data` based on category(in my case it's cuisine). But when I select default value to show `All` data, state doesn't update.
Another problem is about the `duplicated values` in `select option`. I need to have unique values as `option values`. I was thinking about to get unique values this way

```
 <option key={restaurant.id}>{[...new Set(restaurant.cuisine)]}</option>
```

But this removes duplicated characters,but not the `duplicated values`.

Code below.
Hooks/useRestaurants component

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";

const useRestaurants = (cuisine) => {
  const [allRestaurants, setAllRestaurants] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    fetch("https://redi-final-restaurants.herokuapp.com/restaurants")
      .then((res) => res.json())
      .then((result) => setAllRestaurants(result.results))
      .catch((e) => console.log("error"));
  }, []);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (cuisine === "All") {
      const filterRestaurants = [...allRestaurants].filter((restaurant) => // here is my try
       restaurant.cuisine.toLowerCase().includes(cuisine.toLowerCase())//code here doesn't work
      );
      setAllRestaurants(filterRestaurants);
    } else {
      const filterRestaurants = [...allRestaurants].filter((restaurant) =>
        restaurant.cuisine.toLowerCase().includes(cuisine.toLowerCase())
      );
      setAllRestaurants(filterRestaurants);
    }
  }, [cuisine]);

  return [allRestaurants];
};

export default useRestaurants;
```

App.js component

```
import React, { useState } from "react";

import useRestaurants from "./useRestaurants";
import Form from "./Form";
import Restaurant from "./Restaurant";
import "./styles.css";

export default function App() {
  const [cuisine, setCuisine] = useState("All");
  const [allRestaurants] = useRestaurants(cuisine);

  const onChangeHandler = (e) => {
    setCuisine(e.target.value);
  };

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Form
        onChangeHandler={onChangeHandler}
        allRestaurants={allRestaurants}
        cuisine={cuisine}
        setCuisine={setCuisine}
      />
      {allRestaurants &&
        allRestaurants.map((restaurant) => (
          <Restaurant restaurant={restaurant} key={restaurant.id} />
        ))}
    </div>
  );
}
```

And Form.js component

```
import React from "react";

const Form = ({ allRestaurants, cuisine, onChangeHandler }) => {
  return (
    <select onChange={onChangeHandler} value={cuisine}>
      <option value={cuisine}>All</option>
      {allRestaurants.map((restaurant) => (
        <option key={restaurant.id}>{restaurant.cuisine}</option>
      ))}
    </select>
  );
};

export default Form;
```

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The useEffect in `useRestaurants` that is performing the filtering is missing `allRestaurants` from the dependency array. This means that the initial value (an empty array) will always be used within that useEffect. Thus, changing the cuisine will set `allRestaurants` to an empty array. However, you can't add `allRestaurants` to the dependency array and set it from within the effect. That will cause it to loop infinitely. The solution is to not use an effect - just create the filtered result and return it either as a separate value or in place of `allRestaurants`

```
// useRestaurants.js
import { useState, useMemo, useEffect } from "react";

const useRestaurants = (cuisine) => {
  const [allRestaurants, setAllRestaurants] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    fetch("https://redi-final-restaurants.herokuapp.com/restaurants")
      .then((res) => res.json())
      .then((result) => setAllRestaurants(result.results))
      .catch((e) => console.log("error"));
  }, []);

  const filteredRestaurants = useMemo(() => {
    return cuisine === "All"
      ? allRestaurants
      : allRestaurants.filter((restaurant) =>
          restaurant.cuisine.toLowerCase().includes(cuisine.toLowerCase())
        );
  }, [cuisine, allRestaurants]);

  return [allRestaurants, filteredRestaurants];
};

export default useRestaurants;
```

To fix the duplicate cuisine values you need to create the Set and then filter over that result. Your form is still filtering over all `allRestaurants` and `{[...new Set(restaurant.cuisine)]}` is just creating an array with a single value.

```
// Form.js
import React from "react";

const Form = ({ allRestaurants, cuisine, onChangeHandler }) => {
  const cuisines = Array.from(new Set(allRestaurants.map((r) => r.cuisine)));

  return (
    <select onChange={onChangeHandler} value={cuisine}>
      <option value='All'}>All</option>
      {cuisines.map((cuisine) => (
        <option id={cuisine}>{cuisine}</option>
      ))}
    </select>
  );
};

export default Form;
```

Remember to loop over the filtered restaurants in App.js

```
...
const [allRestaurants, filteredRestaurants] = useRestaurants(cuisine);

...
return (
  ...
  {filteredRestaurants &&
    filteredRestaurants.map((restaurant) => (
      <Restaurant restaurant={restaurant} key={restaurant.id} />
  ))}
)
```

Comment: Hi @lurvey, thanks for the answer. That makes a lot of sense.It works fine but partially. 
I just tried the way you typed here, but still didn't update the UI, when I click to "All" option. The goal, I want to achieve, is to show all restaurants when "All" is selected. 
Thanks beforehand.
See the app in codesandbox: 
https://codesandbox.io/s/great-pine-5x263?file=/src/App.js

Comment: I updated my answer. The "All" <option> needs to have the value "All" (`<option value='All'}>All</option>`). What you had was the current cuisine state which changes after selecting a different cuisine, so selecting "All" a second time would just set it to the same cuisine value resulting in no changes.

Comment: Hi @lurvey, thank you  so much. That was very helpful.